# JQUERY: scope issue

Tags: jquery

The two blocks of code work separately alright. They need to work in combination.

Block 1 does:

Upon button click it sends booking start and departure date to the database.

Then the controller does a loop across the table and gets me all of the booked start and end dates AND the days in between.

The response is sent to the jquery and I can actually see it printed out in my View page. Cool. You will identify that in code by the name of : data

2) The second block of code uses some test dates in an array, and they mark red a calendar. So it works in the pickdate.

Therefore what I need is to actually place that Response Data where the array is so that instead of the test dates, I actually have the ones returned by the Controller:

```
<script>             
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

  $('#boton').click(function(){

    var startdate = $('#start_date').val();
    var owner =1;
    var user = 6;
    var enddate = $('#end_date').val();
    $url = '{{URL::route('reservations')}}';

    $.post($url, {arrival:startdate, departure:enddate, user_id:owner, booked_by:user}, function hola (data){   


      $('#test').text(data);

    });


  });

  $myBadDates = new Array("12 September 2015","21 September 2015");

  $(function() {
    $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',            
      beforeShowDay: checkBadDates
    });

  });




  function checkBadDates(mydate){
    var $return=true;
    var $returnclass ="available";
    $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', mydate);
    for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
    {    
      if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
      {
        $return = false;
        $returnclass= "unavailable";
      }
    }
    return [$return,$returnclass];
  }
});
</script>
```

As an ADD-ON info example.The kind of response I am correctly getting is a json series like this one:

```
["16 August 2015","17 August 2015","18 August 2015","19 August 2015","20 August 2015","23 August 2015","24 August 2015","25 August 2015","26 August 2015","27 August 2015","14 September 2015","15 September 2015","16 September 2015","17 September 2015"]
```

It should be easy, but I am stuck for several days ...

UPDATE II

I have made another version which I think is closer but I only get an error saying the call to the function pasamedata is not  defined.

```
<script>             
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('#boton').click(function(){

    var startdate = $('#start_date').val();
    var owner =1;
    var user = 6;
    var enddate = $('#end_date').val();
    $url = '{{URL::route('reservations')}}';

    $.post($url, {
      arrival: startdate,
      departure: enddate,
      user_id: owner,
      booked_by: user
    }, function hola (data) {
     $('#test').text(data);
     pasamedata(data);

    });


  });


 $(function pasamedata(data) {
 var array = data;
        $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', date ), array) > -1)
    {
        return [false,"","Booked out"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [true,'',"available"];
    }
}

            });

    });


 });
 </script>
```

thank you

Comment: *"the controller does a loop across the table"* The controller does *what*?!

Comment: is the $url supposed to be concatenated wrong?

Comment: The controller actually sends the query to the Model, the model does the loop, passes the answer to the controller and the controller returns it to the view (it was selfunderstood(. There is no problem with the url as I am saying that the response of the controller can be correctly prnted out in the View.